# Automatic decompression with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET 7 client that targets a third-party API:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All
};
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)
};


client = new MyClient(httpClient, token);
```

I've tried the above, but it doesn't work.

The API I am targeting with the typed client sends a response that contains a zipped file that contains multiple XML files. Is it possible to configure HttpClient to decompress this file, and access all the decompressed files, and not just the first one?

Comment: Well, no. Wanting to have all files decompressed is a specific application that a generic HTTP client doesn't cater to. All `HttpClient` can do and should do is take care of any compression of the payload on the wire -- it will not take care of processing the file that's downloaded, and that includes archives. You can download or stream the file through `HttpClient` and then leverage `ZipArchive` to process it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That makes sense, thanks! I can see my question was stupid. If you create an answer, I will mark it as solved.

Comment: Your question wasn't stupid. Trust me, I know -- I've seen a *lot* of questions. They're just different kinds of compression, and it's not a huge stretch to think there could be some default handling of archives, since web frameworks do a lot under the covers. That's just not how it happens to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`HttpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.automaticdecompression?view=net-7.0) docs:

> Gets or sets the type of decompression method used by the handler for automatic decompression of the HTTP content response.

From the `HttpClient` standpoint (based on the description you gave) the content is the file itself so the client can take care only of extra compression which could be applied to it during the sending, if the file is an archive you will need to decompress it "manually" (for example via [`ZipArchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.-ctor?view=net-7.0)).